# Do foreign key columns in child table have to be NOT NULL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am using a combination of columns as a primary key and referencing that primary key in a child table. Since it is a combination of multiple columns, is it necessary to define all the columns in the child table with NOT NULL constraints?

E.g., assume that `header` has a primary key with a hash function of the columns A, B and C, and the `line` table has a foreign key with a hash function of the columns A, B and C.
Is it then necessary that the columns A, B and C column in the child table are NOT NULL?

Answer (score 1):

You should consult the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

> Normally, a referencing row need not satisfy the foreign key constraint if any of its referencing columns are null. If MATCH FULL is added to the foreign key declaration, a referencing row escapes satisfying the constraint only if all its referencing columns are null (so a mix of null and non-null values is guaranteed to fail a MATCH FULL constraint). If you don't want referencing rows to be able to avoid satisfying the foreign key constraint, declare the referencing column(s) as NOT NULL.

That is, it's a *choice* you can make, depending on what you do or do not want to allow.